# OpenCV bottle/liquid measurement

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, measurement

Ok, I need to compute the distance between the cap (top of the bottle) and the liquid. I am trying to get the color pixel by pixel from the top down to the liquid. Any ideas how can I do that measure? (I am not sure how to use dilate properly)

[image: bottle]

```
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src = imread("cocaCorte.jpg");
Mat srcTampa, srcLiquido, pixelColor;
Point3_<uchar>* p;
int posicaoX,posicaoY;

void find_moments( Mat grey );

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   ///Criacao das janelas
   cvNamedWindow( "Original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   cvNamedWindow( "Tampa Processada", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   cvNamedWindow( "Liquido Processado", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   cvNamedWindow( "Bitwise OR", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

   ///Processamento do liquido
   inRange( src, Scalar( 0, 0, 0), Scalar( 60, 60, 60), srcLiquido);
   GaussianBlur( srcLiquido, srcLiquido, Size( 7, 7), 5, 5);
   threshold( srcLiquido, srcLiquido, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
   dilate( srcLiquido, srcLiquido, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
   dilate( srcLiquido, srcLiquido, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
   dilate( srcLiquido, srcLiquido, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
   dilate( srcLiquido, srcLiquido, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
   dilate(srcLiquido, srcLiquido, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
   dilate(srcLiquido, srcLiquido, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);

   ///Processamento da tampa
   inRange( src, Scalar( 25, 20, 138), Scalar( 90, 115, 205), srcTampa);
   GaussianBlur( srcTampa, srcTampa, Size( 7, 7), 5, 5);
   threshold( srcTampa, srcTampa, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
   find_moments( srcTampa);

   ///Juntar as duas imagens
   bitwise_or( srcTampa, srcLiquido, pixelColor);

   ///Calculos
   ///Reach the white part represent by the liquid starting fromthe top
   while(true){
        p = pixelColor.ptr<Point3_<uchar> >( posicaoY, posicaoX);
        if((p->z=0)&&(p->y=0)&&(p->x=0)){
            //that means the liquid was found
            break;
        }
        posicaoY++;
   }
   cout<<"FOUND"<<endl; //Print the result...

   ///Mostrar imagens
   imshow("Tampa Processada", srcTampa);
   imshow("Liquido Processado", srcLiquido);
   imshow("Bitwise OR", pixelColor);

   waitKey();
   destroyAllWindows();
   return 0;

}


void find_moments( Mat gray )
{
    Mat canny_output;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    /// Detect edges using canny
    Canny( gray, canny_output, 50, 150, 3 );

    /// Find contours
    findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

    /// Get the moments
    vector<Moments> mu(contours.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    { 
        mu[i] = moments( contours[i], false ); 
    }

    ///  Get the mass centers:
    vector<Point2f> mc( contours.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        mc[i] = Point2f( mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00 , mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00 );
    }
    posicaoX = mc[0].x;
    posicaoY = mc[0].y;


    /// Draw contours
    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar( 255, 0, 0);
        drawContours( src, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
        circle(src, mc[i], 2, color, -1, 1, 0 );
    }

    /// Show in a window
    namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Contours", src );  
}
```

Comment: first of all, please use the opencv c++ api.

Comment: second then , please use the opencv c++ api.

Comment: I improoved my code.